# Javascript initial data strategy

Tags: javascript, jquery

In order to keep my page clean i have created a few javascript files that are combined at production mode into fewer files.
I am using a data- attribute in body to determine which script to run.The problem is that when i need some initial data.In this case i use a script tag and put there a json array with my data. 
These data may change so i am wondering whether it is better to make a json request for the data and not put them in my page directly ?

Comment: Actually, your way is probably faster (the data is available immediately, saving an extra HTTP request).

Comment: and you can still have that data preloaded (as you do) and update it with ajax/jason later (i like it)